# Does ARM support SIMD operations for 64 bit floating point numbers?

Tags: arm, precision, simd

NEON can do SIMD operations for 32 bit float numbers. But does not do SIMD operations for 64 bit float numbers.
VFU is not SIMD. It can do 32 bit or 64 bit floating point operations only on one element.

Does ARM support SIMD operations for 64 bit floating point numbers?

Comment: question is missing.

Comment: Yes and no. Are we talking AArch64 or just 32-bit here?

Comment: @auselen: The question is in the title, but not repeated in the body.

Comment: @Notlikethat, isn't more about ARMv8 vs ARMv7? I think ARM just released a 32-bit ARMv8 chip.

Comment: @Zboson ...and the A32/T32 instruction sets in v8 still have the same NEON instructions as ARM/Thumb in v7. In fact, Cortex-A32 only helps to _dispel_ the "v8 == AArch64" fallacy.

Comment: @Notlikethat, okay, thanks for the info. Why don't you answer the question then? I guess your more or less have in comments but it may be worth writing it up in a formal answer.

Comment: @Notlikethat, 64 bit

Answer (score 3):

This is only possible on processors supporting ARMv8, and only when running Aarch64 instruction set. This is not possible in Aarch32 instruction set.

However most processors support 32-bit and 64-bit scalar floating-point operations (ie floating-point unit).

Comment: are you saying 64 bit simd operation is possible in ARM? if yes, please provide me any link regarding this, wanted to have more information about this.

Comment: Here for example: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.den0024a/CEGDJGGC.html . The last bullet point of the Aarch64 Neon section in paragraph 7.1.

Comment: Thnks Dric512 for the link, ARMv7 does not support double precision vector operation, but ARMv8 support double precision vector operation.

Answer (score 2):

**ARMv8**

In ARMv8, it is possible:

```
fadd v2.2d, v0.2d, v1.2d
```

[Minimal runnable example with an assert and QEMU user setup](https://github.com/cirosantilli/arm-assembly-cheat/blob/8e7dc8fc640d749694b57bff292f7db8a0fdde81/v8/simd.S#L69).

The analogous ARMv7 does *not* work:

```
vadd.f64 q2, q0, q1
```

assembly fails with:

```
bad type in Neon instruction -- `vadd.f64 q2,q0,q1'
```

[Minimal runnable 32-bit float v7 code for comparison](https://github.com/cirosantilli/arm-assembly-cheat/blob/8e7dc8fc640d749694b57bff292f7db8a0fdde81/v7/simd.S#L59).

**Manual**

https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0487/ca/DDI0487C_a_armv8_arm.pdf A1.5 "Advanced SIMD and floating-point support" says:

> The SIMD instructions provide packed Single Instruction Multiple Data (SIMD) and single-element scalar operations, and support:
>
> - Single-precision and double-precision arithmetic in AArch64 state.

For ARMv7, F6.1.27 "VADD (floating-point)" says:

> `<dt>` Is the data type for the elements of the vectors, encoded in the "sz" field. It can have the following values:
>
> F32 when sz = 0
>   F16 when sz = 1

but there is no `F64`, which suggests that it is not possible.