# Arithmetic operations on 64-Bit double values using ARM Neon Intrinsic's in ARM64

Tags: c, x86, neon

I'm trying to implement a simple 64 Bit double addition operation using ARM Neon. I've come across [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36052564/does-arm-support-simd-operations-for-64-bit-floating-point-numbers) but there was no sample implementation using ARM intrinsic available in the answer. So any Help in providing a complete example is greatly appreciated. Here is what i have tried so far by using integer type registers.

Side Note:

Please note that i'm using [intel/ARM_NEON_2_x86_SSE](https://github.com/intel/ARM_NEON_2_x86_SSE/blob/master/ReadMe.md) library for simulating this ARM Neon code using SSE instructions. Should i switch to native ARM neon to test this code?

```
int main()
{
    double Val1[2] = { 2.46574621,0.46546221};
    double Val2[2] = { 2.63565654,0.46574621};
    double Sum[2] = { 0.0,0.0 };
    double Sum_C[2] = { 0.0,0.0};   

    vst1q_s64(Sum,                      //Store int64x2_t
        vaddq_s64(                      //Add   int64x2_t
            vld1q_s64(&(Val1[0])),      //Load  int64x2_t
            vld1q_s64(&(Val2[0])) ));   //Load  int64x2_t

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        Sum_C[i] = Val1[i] + Val2[i];
        if (Sum_C[i] != Sum[i])
        {
            cout << "[Error]    Sum : " << Sum[i] << "  !=  " << Sum_C[i] << "\n";
        }
        else
            cout << "[Passed]   Sum : " << Sum[i] << "  ==  " << Sum_C[i] << "\n";
    }  

    cout << "\n";
}
```

---

```
[Error] Sum : -1.22535e-308     !=  5.1014
[Error] Sum : 1.93795e+307      !=  0.931208
```

Comment: `vaddq_s64` is signed-integer, as a quick google will tell you: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491f/BABDFJCI.html.  Obviously integer add of FP bit-patterns doesn't give you an FP add operation.  Another search for `float64x2_t` found that `vaddq_f64` exists, so presumably that's what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double precision isn't supported on `aarch32` NEON.

Therefore, if you target `armv7-a` while using the data type `float64x2_t`, it won't build.

If your test platform is an `aarch64` one with a 64-bit OS installed, just exclude the `aarch32` target from your makefile.